# Moodle Filters with SQL-UNION

Tags: moodle

How can we get to work the moodle filters when UNION is come up in an SQL query. The below code shows the filter form where filters aren't working. The code works when UNION is not used.

```
require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/filter_form.php');    
$mform = new filter_form();
$firstnamefilter = '';
$lastnamefilter = '';
if ($formdata = $mform->get_data()) {
    $firstnamefilter = $formdata->firstname;
    $lastnamefilter = $formdata->lastname;
}

$toform->id = $id;
$mform->set_data($toform);
$mform->display();

$reporttable = new html_table();
$reporttable->head = array('Name', 'Email');
$reporttable->attributes['class'] = 'table';

$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email FROM {user} JOIN {user_enrolments} ue
        ON u.id= ue.userid WHERE u.id = '.$id.'

        UNION

        SELECT ae.id, ae.username, ae.firstname, ae.lastname, ae.email FROM {auth_user} JOIN {user_enrolments} ue
        ON ae.id= ue.userid WHERE u.id = '.$id.'

        ";

$params = array();
if (!empty($firstnamefilter)) {
    $params['firstname'] = '%' . $DB->sql_like_escape($firstnamefilter) . '%';  
    $sql .= " AND " . $DB->sql_like('u.firstname', ':firstname', false);

} else if (!empty($lastnamefilter)) {
    $params['lastname'] = '%' . $DB->sql_like_escape($lastnamefilter) . '%';    
    $sql .= " AND " . $DB->sql_like('u.lastname', ':lastname', false);
}

$mds = $DB->get_recordset_sql($sql, $params);

foreach ($mds $m) {

    $reporttable->data[] = new html_table_row(array(implode(array($m->firstname. $m->lastname)), $m->email ));
}                              
echo html_writer::table($reporttable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great that you are using the proper like functions!

For the SQL, you need to use a separate where for each union rather than at the end. You were also using `u.id = $id` which would have restricted it to one user id.

So I've reworked your SQL - this should work.

```
$params = array();
$wheres1 = array();
$wheres2 = array();

if (!empty($firstnamefilter)) {
    $params['firstname1'] = '%' . $DB->sql_like_escape($firstnamefilter) . '%';
    $params['firstname2'] = $params['firstname1'];
    $wheres1[] = $DB->sql_like('u.firstname', ':firstname1', false);
    $wheres2[] = $DB->sql_like('ae.firstname', ':firstname2', false);
}

if (!empty($lastnamefilter)) {
    $params['lastname1'] = '%' . $DB->sql_like_escape($lastnamefilter) . '%';
    $params['lastname2'] = $params['lastname1'];
    $wheres1[] = $DB->sql_like('u.lastname', ':lastname1', false);
    $wheres2[] = $DB->sql_like('ae.lastname', ':lastname2', false);
}

$where1 = '';
$where2 = '';
if (!empty($wheres1)) {
    $where1 = "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $wheres1);
    $where2 = "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $wheres2);
}

$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email
        FROM {user} u
        JOIN {user_enrolments} ue ON u.id = ue.userid
        {$where1}

        UNION

        SELECT ae.id, ae.username, ae.firstname, ae.lastname, ae.email
        FROM {auth_user} ae
        JOIN {user_enrolments} ue ON ae.id = ue.userid
        {$where2}";
```